# Background Scrolling is possible whilst menu is open(Codepen Included)

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar which disappears whilst scrolling up. When I open the hamburger menu, however, I am still able to have background scrolling as the navbar disappears. Is there a way to have the navbar static(in smaller windows) or just be able to disable background scrolling when the menu is open? Codepen Included below:

https://codepen.io/blairhunter/pen/PoNYOzj

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
       document.getElementById("diss").style.top = "0";
      } else {
   document.getElementById("diss").style.top = "-81.5px";
  }
 prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you want sticky menu bar ?

Comment: I want the navbar to disappear upon scrolling but not to disappear when the hamburger menu is open

Comment: i can''t understand your question .. you can check the link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky.. may be it will help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you want:

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("diss").classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("diss").classList.add("hide");
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#diss {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

#diss.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

nav{
  background: white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

label.logo{
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 130px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 130px;
}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
a.active,a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.checkbtn{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px){
  label.logo{
    font-size: 27px;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 858px){
  .checkbtn{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }


  ul{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #212120;
    top: 81.5px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }

  nav ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
  }

  a:hover,a.active{
    background: none;
    color: white;
  }

  #check:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
  }
}

/* Content */

.divide {
  height:1.5px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
}

.main {
  margin-top:80px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:#212120;
}

.detail {
  font-size:30px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color:#fbccc9;
  padding-left: 130px;
  padding-right:130px;
  padding-top:15px;
}

.pagetitle {
  font-size:46px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color:white;
  padding-left: 130px;
  padding-right:130px;
  padding-top:100px;
}

@media (max-width: 952px){
  .pagetitle{
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top:50px;
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .detail{
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .main {
    height:310px;
  }

  .diss {
      position:fixed;
  }
}

/* Container */
.container {
  padding-left: 130px;
  padding-right:130px;
}

.heading {
  font-size:30px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top:25px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

@media (max-width: 952px){
  .container{
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

  /* Project Boxes */

  .row {
    margin: 8px -16px;
  }

  /* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
  .row,
  .row > .column {
    padding: 8px;
  }

  /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }

  /* Clear floats after rows */
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  /* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
  @media screen and (max-width: 952px) {
    .column {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }

  /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.jpg"/>

        <div id="diss">
              <nav>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </label>
                <label class="logo">Name</label>
                <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="divide"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="divide"></div>
  </head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<h1 class="pagetitle">Hello, this is the main text.<h1>
<h2 class="detail">This is the subheading here</h2>
</div>

<section class="container">
  <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>

  <!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="img/placement.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="img/placement.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="img/placement.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="img/placement.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <!-- END GRID -->
  </div>

</section>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I'll give it a go. Really appreciate you taking the time :)

Comment: Brilliant - that's it sorted. Cheers again. Some man!